# Ionic 3 header height on IOS 10 or 11

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm building a mobile application using ionic 3

Anyway, When I running this application using browser or Ionic view everything is okay, But, when you run it on real device or IPhone simulator the height of header changed and come bigger.

Please check the following image.

[On browser or ionic view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4cWp.png)

VS

[On Real Device or simulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d9bz.png)

Comment: Use ionic [status bar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/) to make it overlay your app. `this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 11, you have to add `viewport-fit=cover` to the `viewport` meta tag of your index.html file for the WebView to extends under the status bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>An Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

See Ionic checklist for more information: http://blog.ionic.io/ios-11-checklist/